# How to set tooltip for buttonbar button

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, adobe

I have a `buttonbar` that has 3 buttons. I'm trying to set a tooltip for each of the buttons, but not sure where. The `ButtonBar` itself has a skin, which in turn includes a skin for each of the buttons.

```
<s:ButtonBar id="bb" selectedIndex="0" skinClass="skins.bbSkin">
     <s:dataProvider>
          <s:ArrayList>
              <fx:Object label="item1" />
              <fx:Object label="item2" />
              <fx:Object label="item3" />
         </s:ArrayList>
     </s:dataProvider>
</s:ButtonBar>
```

The skin for the `buttonbar` is `skins.bbSkin`

The skin inside it for each button is `skins.bbbSkin`

Answer (score 3):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
<mx:ButtonBar id="bb" selectedIndex="0" toolTipField="tooltip">
    <mx:dataProvider>
         <mx:Array>
             <mx:Object label="item1" tooltip='hello1'/>
             <mx:Object label="item2" tooltip='hello2'/>
             <mx:Object label="item3" tooltip='hello3'/>
        </mx:Array>
    </mx:dataProvider>
   </mx:ButtonBar>
</mx:Application>
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
<mx:ButtonBar id="bb" selectedIndex="0" toolTipField="tooltip">
    <mx:dataProvider>
         <mx:Array>
             <mx:Object label="item1" tooltip='hello1'/>
             <mx:Object label="item2" tooltip='hello2'/>
             <mx:Object label="item3" tooltip='hello3'/>
        </mx:Array>
    </mx:dataProvider>
   </mx:ButtonBar>
</mx:Application>

Comment: hey plzz use this code in comments, i did put that in answer, but don't know the code is not getting displayed,

use toolTipField property of the button bar

Comment: I fixed it for you.  You need to paste the code in, select it all and then click the code icon in the wysiwyg (it looks like 1's and 0's)

Comment: Thanx Ryan for this, i was a bit confused wht to do in this case, so i pasted the code in comments

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display a toolTip with the spark ButtonBar you have to manage with the skinClass.
Have a look here :
https://sensaran.wordpress.com/2010/07/19/setting-tooltip-for-spark-buttonbar

Comment: Please include relevant information from the link in your answer. If that website becomes unavailable your answer is likely to be downvoted or deleted.